# Why am I getting ORA-02180, if my CREATE TABLESPACE command syntax is correct?

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

I am trying to create a new temporary tablespace for testing purposes (the code to be tested is actually designed to work with an external Oracle database, all the important tables sharing the same tablespace named `sbrdwh').

To test the code, I have to create my own db with the same schema and the same tablespace, but when it comes to the latter, ORA-02180 is thrown.

My command looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE sbrdwh FILE '/tmp/sbrdwh.dbf' SIZE 10M;
```

What am I doing wrongly?

The user who issues this command has privileges to create tablespaces and unlimited tablespace quota.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE sbrdwh TEMPFILE '/tmp/sbrdwh.dbf' SIZE 10M;
```

didn't work also.

Comment: Do you have proper security access? If your syntax is correct but you are receiving errors then the first thing to check is your security privileges.

Comment: @DanK Thank you, I have already checked it -- more than that, I have granted unlimited tablespace privilege to the user.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct keyword is `DATAFILE` or `TEMPFILE`, not `FILE`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE sbrdwh TEMPFILE '/tmp/sbrdwh.dbf' SIZE 10M;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still throws ORA-02180.